# Access variable from one role in another role in an Ansible playbook with multiple hosts

Tags: ansible

I'm using the latest version of Ansible, and I am trying to use a default variable in `role-one` used on host `one`, in `role-two`, used on host `two`, but I can't get it to work.

Nothing I have found in the documentation or on StackOverflow has really helped. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Ideally I want to set the value of the variable once, and be able to use it in another role for any host in my playbook.

I've broken it down below.

---

In my inventory I have a hosts group called `[test]` which has two hosts aliased as `one` and `two`.

```
[test]
one ansible_host=10.0.1.10 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=centos ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<path_to_key>
two ansible_host=10.0.1.20 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=centos ansible_ssh_private_key_file=<path_to_key>
```

I have a *single playbook* with a *play for each of these hosts* and I supply the `hosts:` value as `"{{ host_group }}[0]"` for host `one` and `"{{ host_group }}[1]"` for host `two`.

The play for host `one` uses a role called `role-one` and the play for host `two` uses a role called `role-two`.

```yaml
- name: Test Sharing Role Variables
  hosts: "{{ host_group }}[0]"
  roles:
    - ../../ansible-roles/role-one

- name: Test Sharing Role Variables
  hosts: "{{ host_group }}[1]"
  roles:
    - ../../ansible-roles/role-two
```

In `role-one` I have set a variable `variable-one`.

```yaml
---
# defaults file for role-one

variable_one: Role One Variable
```

I want to use the value of `variable_one` in a template in `role-two` but I haven't had any luck. I'm using the below as a task in `role-two` to test and see if the variable is getting "picked-up".

```yaml
---
# tasks file for role-two
- debug:
    msg: "{{ variable_one }}"
```

When I run the playbook with `ansible-playbook test.yml --extra-vars "host_group=test"` I get the below failure.

```sh
TASK [../../ansible-roles/role-two : debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [two]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['test']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'ansible-roles/role-two/tasks/main.yml': line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n# tasks file for role-two\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Variables declared in roles are scoped to the play. If you want to access a variable from `role-one` in `role-two`, they would both need to be in the same play.  For example, you could write:

```
- name: Test Sharing Role Variables
  hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: role-one
      when: inventory_hostname == "one"

    - import_role:
        name: role-two
      when: inventory_hostname == "two"
```

Alternatively, you could restructure your roles so that the variables can be imported separately from your actions.  That is, have a `role_one_vars` role that does nothing but define variables, and then you can import that in both `role-one` and `role-two`.  That is, you would have a structure something like:

```
playbook.yml
hosts
roles/
  role-one/
    tasks/
      main.yml
  role-one-vars/
    variables/
      main.yml
  role-two/
    tasks/
      main.yml
```

And `role-one/tasks/main.yml` would look like:

```
- import_role:
    name: role-one-vars

- debug:
    msg: "in role-one: {{ variable_one }}"
```

`role-two/tasks/main.yml` would look like:

```
---
- import_role:
    name: role-one-vars

- debug:
    msg: "in role-two: {{ variable_one }}"
```

And `role-one-vars/vars/main.yml` would look like:

```
---
variable_one: role one variable
```

Putting this all together, the output looks like:

```
PLAY [Test Sharing Role Variables] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [one]

TASK [role-one : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [one] => {
    "msg": "in role-one: role one variable"
}

PLAY [Test Sharing Role Variables] *****************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [two]

TASK [role-two : debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [two] => {
    "msg": "in role-two: role one variable"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
one                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
two                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: it was so handy answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Q: **"*Access variable from one role in another role in an Ansible playbook with multiple hosts*"**

A: Short answer: Use *set_fact* and put the variable into the *hostvars*.

Details: Given the roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role-one/defaults/main.yml 
variable_one: Role One Variable

shell> cat roles/role-one/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: variable_one

shell> cat roles/role-two/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: variable_one
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: one
  roles:
    - role-one
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: variable_one

- hosts: two
  roles:
    - role-two

- hosts: one
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: variable_one
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [role-one : debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

PLAY [two] ************************************************

TASK [role-two : debug] ****
ok: [two] => 
  variable_one: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

As expected, the variable *variable_one* is visible to the tasks in the first play. But, there is no reason the variable should be visible to the host *two* in the second play. The variable is not visible also to the same host in the third play because it hasn't been stored in the *hostvars* aka "instantiated". The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: one
  roles:
    - role-one
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: variable_one
    - set_fact:
        variable_one: "{{ variable_one }}"

- hosts: two
  roles:
    - role-two

- hosts: one
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: variable_one
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [role-one : debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [one]

PLAY [two] ************************************************

TASK [role-two : debug] ****
ok: [two] => 
  variable_one: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable
```

Now, the variable is visible to the host *one* in the whole playbook and can be visible to other hosts using *hostvars* as well. For example, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: one
  roles:
    - role-one
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: variable_one
    - set_fact:
        variable_one: "{{ variable_one }}"

- hosts: two
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        variable_one: "{{ hostvars.one.variable_one }}"
    - include_role:
        name: role-two
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [role-one : debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [one]

PLAY [two] ************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [two]

TASK [include_role : role-two] ****

TASK [role-two : debug] ****
ok: [two] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable
```

---

The problem with the above setting is that the host referencing *hostvars* is hardcoded. A better approach is to "instantiate" the variable in the first play for all hosts. For example, add a dummy task to the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role-one/tasks/noop.yml
- meta: noop
```

Then, in the first play, include all hosts, *run_once* import the role, run the dummy task only, and "instantiate" the variable for all hosts. For example

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: role-one
        tasks_from: noop.yml
      run_once: true
    - set_fact:
        variable_one: "{{ variable_one }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: two
  roles:
    - role-two

- hosts: one
  roles:
    - role-two
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [all] ************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [one]

PLAY [two] ************************************************

TASK [role-two : debug] ****
ok: [two] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable

PLAY [one] ************************************************

TASK [role-two : debug] ****
ok: [one] => 
  variable_one: Role One Variable
```